# Making a GET HTTP Request in An Excel JavaScript Add-In

Tags: excel, reactjs, typescript, office-js

All right, so web development is something new to me so I wasn't exactly sure what I needed to provide so I want to also provide a link to the repo that contains this code: [Excel Add-In Repo](https://github.com/areed1192/new-office-add-in)

---

## Problem:

Right now, I'm in the process of building an Excel Add-In using the new JavaScript API. I am currently using the "React Framework" task pane template that is provided by the `yo office generator`. Inside of my add-in I want to make a web request to the following URL: https://www.sec.gov/files/company_tickers.json

Every time I make the request it returns an error. Here is how the request look:

```js
 // I assign this function on line 115.
  fetchCikNumbers = async () => {

    try {

      // Make a new HTTP Request.
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      // Define the Method and URL.
      xhr.open('GET', `https://www.sec.gov/files/company_tickers.json`);

      // Maybe set the "Access-Control" header?
      // xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');

      // Print the Text to the Console.
      xhr.onload = function (e) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
        console.log(e);
      }

      // Send the Request.
      xhr.send();

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }

  }
```

Initially, this is the error I got:

[image: request error]

---

## Here is what I've tried:

- I looked online and they mentioned I should add the URL to a `<AppDomain></AppDomain>` tag in my manifest file. However, that didn't fix the issue either.
- I added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to my headers when making a request. When I do that, it just says it can't find the identified Resource URI.

[image]

## Additional Notes:

I'm just not sure what it could be, and to make things even weirder if I make a normal call to a regular API like Alpha Vantage, I have no issues. Now, I will say that the `SEC` has weird pages that don't seem to be formatted correctly. For example, even though it points to a JSON URL the data doesn't seem like it's properly coded as such.

Comment: What URL did you use in  <AppDomain>? Also, Access-Control-Allow-Origin isn't a request header, it's a response header. Adding it to your request won't solve the problem.

Comment: @Andrew this is what I have in my add domain currently.     <AppDomain>https://www.sec.gov</AppDomain> <AppDomain>https://www.sec.gov/files/company_tickers.json</AppDomain>

Comment: I believe the appdomain requires the https. Try putting in https://sec.gov in there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71461455/5079799